# Python HTML Extract text into List

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to extract all text on a html page into a list split by tag. For example if the HTML looked like the below:

```
<div>Hello
    <span>World Test This</span>
    <p>HTML</p>
</div>
<span>Extraction</span
```

I would like the Output list to form like the below:

```
["Hello","World Test This","HTML","Extraction"]
```

I have tried using .get_text() but I can't iterate through that and the only other option i tried was .find() however that didn't work either as i used  as the find followed by the .get_text() which did what i wanted however if there were other tags with text within a DIV it would combine all those as one.

Any help would be amazing thanks!

Comment: Hi, the rules for how you'd like to arrive at this output are slightly ambiguous. Do you just want to remove all the HTML tags and have each line of text be its own element in the list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`HTMLParser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html#example-html-parser-application) class from the [**`standard library`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) to parse the HTML. It has a [`handle_data`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html#html.parser.HTMLParser.handle_data) method which is called to process arbitrary data.

```
>>> from html.parser import HTMLParser
>>>
>>> class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
...     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
...         self.data = []
...         super(MyHTMLParser, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
...     def handle_data(self, data):
...         data = data.strip()
...         if data:
...             self.data.append(data)
...
>>> parser = MyHTMLParser()
>>>
>>> parser.feed("""
... <div>Hello
...     <span>World Test This</span>
...     <p>HTML</p>
... </div>
... <span>Extraction</span>
... """)
>>>
>>> print(parser.data)
['Hello', 'World Test This', 'HTML', 'Extraction']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeautifulSoup for this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html= """<div>Hello
    <span>World Test This</span>
    <p>HTML</p>
</div>
<span>Extraction</span>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
words = soup.text.replace('\n\n', '\n').replace('  ','').lstrip().splitlines()
print(words)
```

`['Hello', 'World Test This', 'HTML', 'Extraction']`

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension with `re`gex:

```
print([i.strip() for i in re.sub('<.*?>', '', s).splitlines() if i])
```

Output:

```
['Hello', 'World Test This', 'HTML', 'Extraction']
```